# how to increment pointer to pointer so the address of next char * character is get pointed to

Tags: c

I have this code

```
 char *c="hello";
 char **p=&c;
 *c++;
 *c++;
  printf("%s\n",*p);
```

But I don't want to increment c like `*c++`. instead I want to increment p so `lo` is printed out if I do something like *p++`(does not work still prints wrong probably prints address)`

Comment: *(*p)++ had to do this;

Comment: You probably want this: `printf("%s\n", (*p) + 3);`. Anyway you cannot increment `p`, otherwise it will just point some garbage.

Comment: You can not increase p because it points to a stringpointer, not a string. If you increase p, then it points to some different stringpointer which is a different string. In your case it will be undefined, and invokes undefined behavior. As Alex pointed out, you can increase the pointer, that p points to, if this is what you intended by saying to not increase c.

Comment: This is unclear. What does this code do? What do you want it to do instead.

Comment: Re “*(*p)++ had to do this”: The first asterisk is unnecessary. `(*p)++` suffices to increment the pointer that `p` points to. You could also write `*p += 1;`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to increment p so `lo` is printed

That would require incrementing `*p`, not `p`. In other words, incrementing `c` via `p`. This can be done with: `(*p)++`.

The parentheses are needed to first do `*p` in order to get the value that `p` is pointing to (i.e. `c`), and then `++` to increment it.

Without the parentheses,  `*p++` is the same as `*(p++)`, i.e. it increments `p` to point past `c`, and then dereferences the pointer. The result of the dereference is not used so it's the same as just `p++`.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   char *c="hello";
 char **p=&c;
 (*p)++;
 (*p)++;
  printf("%s\n",*p);
    return 0;
}
```